# Symfony bundle not found in appkernel

Tags: symfony

I have create a new bundle for my vendor.

I have my bundle, i add it in appkernel, in routing.yml, but i have this error :

```
Class '...\TestBundle' not found in /.../AppKernel.php on line 23
```

When i click on my testbundle in appkernel, that return me my php 'testbundle'

```
class TestBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Comment: Post `AppKernel` AND your data folder structure + namespace (if any) of `TestBundle`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, i have forgot to add it in git, now its ok that work nice